# awk : loop through tab delimited file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting

Input csv file has the below content, which is tab delimited.

```
3915    LOW Thia Khiang LIU
```

I need to find 4th item which happens to be "LIU" in the above case.

But, below script is printing "Khiang". It is considering space as tab.

```
awk '{print "UID="$1"\tLN="$2"\tAlias="$4}' myInputFile.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify tab as the field separator explicitly:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print "UID="$1"\tLN="$2"\tAlias="$4}' myInputFile.csv
UID=3915    LN=LOW  Alias=LIU
```

By default (and when specifying a *literal space* as the field separator), `awk` considers any line-internal run of spaces and/or tabs a (single) field separator (and additionally trims leading and trailing whitespace).

Comment: You can also use `{printf "UID=%s\tLN=%s\tAlias=%s\n",$1,$2,$4}` or even `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print "UID="$1,"LN="$2,"Alias="$4}`.